# How to calculate the statistical persistence of a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, dataframe

Suppose I have a series:

```
from pandas import Series
x = Series([2.3,6.7,1.2,8.0,7.5])
```

I want to calculate the correlation. If I do this:

```
shift = x[:-1]
x = x[1:]
x.corr(shift)
```

Because the Series remembers the original indices of each element, it matches them up by index and I always get a correlation of 1.0.

What's the most elegant way to do this without manually writing my own correlation function? (Which I can do, but I want clean code.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with parameter `periods` :

```
from pandas import Series

x = Series([2.3,6.7,1.2,8.0,7.5])

shift = x.shift(periods=1)
print shift
0    NaN
1    2.3
2    6.7
3    1.2
4    8.0
dtype: float64

y = x[1:]
print y
1    6.7
2    1.2
3    8.0
4    7.5
dtype: float64

print y.corr(shift)
-0.429976085769
```

Or:

```
from pandas import Series

x = Series([2.3,6.7,1.2,8.0,7.5])
print x

shift = x.shift(periods=-1)
print shift
0    6.7
1    1.2
2    8.0
3    7.5
4    NaN
dtype: float64

y = x[1:]
print y
1    6.7
2    1.2
3    8.0
4    7.5
dtype: float64

print y.corr(shift)
-0.397282761402
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.corr(x.shift())
x.autocorr()
```